get_results returning objects with only the post ID
I am having problems with a custom page type in the plugin SportsPress. Sometimes the page for these posts are displayed as a 'blank' post. It seems to be intermittent.
On digging into the plugin, they have hooked into the 'the_posts' filter with the following function:
    public function display_scheduled_events( $posts ) {
    global $wp_query, $wpdb;
    if ( is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0 && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['sp_event'] ) ) {
        $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request );
    }
    return $posts;
}

If I log $posts before the line $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request ); I get a fully formed post object:
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 53851
            [post_author] => 367
            [post_date] => 2023-08-09 19:00:00
            [post_date_gmt] => 2023-08-09 18:00:00
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => My post title
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => 53851
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2023-08-15 21:08:18
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2023-08-15 20:08:18
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => https://my-website.co.uk/?post_type=sp_event&#038;p=53851
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => sp_event
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

)

But when I log $posts after that line, this is what it contains:
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 53851
        )

)

As you can see, the post is not a scheduled/future post. I have been unable to replicate locally, which suggests that it may be environmental. What is happening in WordPress for it return what seems to be skeleton objects?

I'm not familiar with this specific plugin, but could you just do something like if(!$thing instanceof \WP_Post){$thing = get_post($thing->ID);}

$wpdb->get_results( $request ) will not retrieve post objects but the database's data asked for in $request, so check what your $wp_query->request evaluates to.
To get post objects, you would actually call get_posts() on the WP_Query object.
